# Listen then send on subscribe with RxJava

Tags: java, android, concurrency, rx-java

I keep running into situations where I want to be able to listen for a response to a request via RxJava. The problem is I am not sure how to set up the Observable so that I am listening for events and send the message on subscribe in the correct order. I don't want to send the message then listen because, if the thread gets suspended or the response is super fast, I could miss it. This is the closest I could think of on my own

```
connection.onReceivedMessage()
          .doOnSubscribe(() -> connection.send(message))
          .filter(message -> message.id == id)
          ... // do stuff
```

or

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
    connection.send(message);
    return connection.onReceivedMessage();
})... // do stuff
```

But these still seem like I could still send the message and not be listening for the response. Has anyone else tried to do this? I feel like I really want a sort of afterCreate().

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to send the message then listen because, if the thread
>   gets suspended or the response is super fast, I could miss it.

Use a `Subject`. Either a `BehaviorSubject` (emits always the latest observable emitted to new subscriber) or a `ReplySubject` (emits all the `Observable` emitted to new subscriber). I am not sure about the whole logic, but you could have something like:

```
 public BehaviorSubject mMessageBehaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();


private void sendMessage() {
    connection.onReceivedMessage()
          .doOnSubscribe(() -> connection.send(message))
          .filter(message -> message.id == id)
          .subscribe(mSubject::onNext, Throwable::printStackTrace);
}


public Observable<String> getMessageObservable() {
     return mMessageBehaviorSubject.asObservable();
}
```

this way you could send the message and whenever you are ready to listen yu will get, in this case, latest message sent

Answer (score 0):

doOnSubscribe is exactly what you need, it's the "afterCreate" you are looking for. In your first example, the first message will be send after subscription, at this time the Observable is already ready to handle response.

As for your question - Has anyone else tried to do this? - the response is yes. I use same technique as your first example to rxify some piece of codes.

Comment: doOnSubscribe works like that? I will have to test this more. I will admit I never made a unit test to verify.